# Binary quadratic function, when it is equal to a square number?

Tags: gcd-and-lcm, pell-type-equations

$x^2+5xy+3y^2=T$ and $\gcd(x,y)=1$

T is a square number. I need to find which x and y values make the function a square number. Gcd is a greatest common divisor function.

I converted the function Into a pell equation which discriminant is 13, but another way to seach a solution?

Comment: What was the eventual result when you converted to Pell equations? Can you add a bit of detail in your answer about this approach, and why you're looking for a different one?

Comment: you have misinterpreted. What you have is not Pell as such; it is an isotropic ternary quadratic form, with parametrization similar to that of Pythagorean triples. I gave one such, it will take me some time to find out if that is enough.

Comment: Thanks for the help, because I want  faster algorithm, my previous approach iş slow when the x and y values are large numbers like pow(10,20)

Comment: I converted the main function Into this
(2x+5y)^2-13y^2=4f^2

Comment: I looked up some things;  your question would be a reasonable project for a number theory class   emphasizing calculations. In particular, one using the Zagier reduction of indefinite binary quadratic forms. Note, however, that such methods are known to be slower than the original Gauss-Lagrange reduction.

Answer (score 3):

in the book Diophantine Equations by Mordell, page 47, Theorem 4 says that the isotropic vectors of a ternary quadratic form  can be parametrized with one or more "Pythagorean Triple" type formulas. I wrote one of them below.

Write it as $x^2 + 5xy + 3y^2  = z^2 $  and take

$$  x = u^2 - 2uv - 2 v^2 \; , \; \; y = 2uv  + 3 v^2 \; , \; \; z = u^2 + 3 uv - v^2  $$

Comment: Can we wrlte the function with u's and v's fourth exponents?

Comment: @eagleofnorth  with what purpose?   Above, when you said "faster algorithm,"  faster algorithm to do what?

Comment: I have been trying to write a code to have a fast solution, just curious.

Comment: @eagleofnorth  You seem to like coding projects, not necessarily from current contests. Where did you get this one?  What is the exact wording of their original problem?

Comment: Actually a friend of mine asked me since she knows that I like to solve this kind of problems, and I am not sure whether this problem is from a contest or not. What is asked in the question is to figure out x and y values where T is in the range between 1 and 10^30 and GCD(x,y) should be 1.

Comment: And I think very tough problem.

Comment: @eagleofnorth  It is elaborate. Everything needed is in Buell, Binary Quadratic Forms. Dirichley composition (for $u^2 + 3uv - v^2$)  is on page 57. You need to be able to factor $z = \sqrt T,$  then for each prime factor $p$ solve $\beta^2 \equiv \pmod p,$   with $\beta$ odd, giving $b^2 - 4p \gamma = 13,$ then reduce binary form  $\langle p, \beta, \gamma \rangle $    to     $\langle 1, 3, -1 \rangle $   and keep track of the 2 by 2 matrix used. REduction is pages 21-23  especially.

Comment: actually $ \beta^2 \equiv 13 \pmod p  $  Also a book by Buchmann and Vollmer, same title.  If any prime factors are large, one will need https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tonelli%E2%80%93Shanks_algorithm or

Comment: for comparison  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cornacchia%27s_algorithm

Comment: Thanks, I will check it.